# update property based on outcome of linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use linq to group some data then update a propety based on on the values from the query.

e.g.

```
 var list = from c in Transactions()
                group c by c.StoreID into g
                select new TransactionDetail{ 
                  Description = g.FirstOrDefault().Descrip,
                  BusinessName = g.FirstOrDefault().BusinessName,
                  TransactionAmount = g.Where(cr => cr.EntryType == cnCommon.INSERT_ENTRY).Sum(cr=>cr.TransactionAmount).Value,
                 PurchasesRequired = g.FirstOrDefault().PurchasesNeeded

                };

        foreach (TransactionDetail item in list)
        {
            item.ProgressBar = (230 / item.PurchasesRequired) *Convert.ToInt32(item.TransactionAmount);
        }


        lstTransactions.DataSource = list.ToList();
        lstTransactions.DataBind();


    }

    public class TransactionDetail
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string BusinessName { get; set; }
        public double TransactionAmount { get; set; }
        public double TransactionsCompleted { get; set; }
        public int PurchasesRequired { get; set; }
        public bool IsRedeemable { get; set; }
        public int Balance { get; set; }
        public int ProgressBar { get; set; }
    }
```

The query works ok but when I do the foreach loop TransactionDetail.ProgressBar isnt updated.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is Transactions()? Is this LINQ-to-Objects or LINQ-to-SQL?

Perhaps you can't modify a property of an object in the list while it's looping through it. Try adding ".ToList()" to "list" like so:

```
var list = (from c in Transactions() 
           group c by c.StoreID into g 
           select new TransactionDetail{  
               Description = g.FirstOrDefault().Descrip, 
               BusinessName = g.FirstOrDefault().BusinessName, 
               TransactionAmount = g.Where(cr => cr.EntryType == cnCommon.INSERT_ENTRY).Sum(cr=>cr.TransactionAmount).Value, 
               PurchasesRequired = g.FirstOrDefault().PurchasesNeeded  
                }).ToList();
```

THEN loop through the results.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem here is the following part of the equation

```
(230 / item.PurchasesRequired)
```

item.PurchasesRequired is an int, and therefore if it's higher than 230, the result will be 0, and when you multiply 0 by item.TransactionAmount it's still 0 regardless of the TransactionAmoutn value. Even if PurchasesRequired are lower than 230, it will make it very unprecise since a PurchaseRequired of 230 and 120 will give you the same result.

Try to form the formula like this instead:

```
(int)((230*item.TransactionAmount) / item.PurchasesRequired)
```

Comment: Thanks for the formula tip :)

Comment: However if I place a breakpoint on lstTransactions.DataSource = list.ToList(); none of the changes from the foreach loop have been applied